# Gap between UL and its parent LI in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

As the title is saying I got a big gap in my menu which occurs in Chrome but not in Firefox:

[image: screenshot]
**EDIT**
[image: screenshot2]

```css
body {color:#333;
      background:#2c2c2c;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      width: 1200px;
      font-size:75%;
      font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}

h1,h2    {font-weight: normal; color:#38D2F3;}
h1    {font-size:1.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em;}
h2    {font-size: 1.2em; margin-bottom: 0.75em;}
p   {color: white}


.container {
    position:absolute;
    width:1150px;
    height: 100%;
}

#page {
    height:100%;
}

#header{
    padding: 10 10 0 10;
    width: 1150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #9AC0CD;
}

#navigation{
    position: inherit;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
}

ul.nav hr{
    width: 90%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    border: none;
    background: white;
}

ul.nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-color: gray;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding:0;
}

li.nav{
    position: relative;

}

li.nav a, li.nav-last a, li.nav-first a{
    display: block;
    height: 30px;   
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 10px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

li.nav-last a{
    border: none;
}

li.nav:hover a, li.nav-last:hover a, li.nav-first:hover a{
    background-color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.nav-first:hover a{
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

ul.sub-nav li.sub-nav a {
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
}

ul.sub-nav li.sub-nav:hover a {
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

li.nav ul.sub-nav,li.nav-first ul.sub-nav,li.nav-last ul.sub-nav{
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    left: 188px;
    top:0px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: gray;
    border-width: 1px;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    z-index: 10;
}

li.nav:hover ul.sub-nav, li.nav-first:hover ul.sub-nav, li.nav-last:hover ul.sub-nav {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

#content{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 230px;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./script/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="page">
     <div class="container">
      <div id="header">HEADER</div>
      <div id="navigation">
       <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-first"><a href="#">Eintrag 1</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 1</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 2</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <hr />
                    </li>

        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Eintrag 2</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 1</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 2</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <hr />
                    </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Eintrag 3</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 1</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 2</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <hr />
                        </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Eintrag 4</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 1</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 2</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <hr />
                    </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Eintrag 5</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 1</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 2</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <hr />
                    </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Eintrag 6</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 1</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 2</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Untereinstrag 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <hr />
                    </li>
        <li class="nav-last"><a href="#">Eintrag 7</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   

Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.   

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I think it might occur due to the "position: relative" but haven't found a workaround yet.

Here is the CSS-code

I seriously can't get my head around why this ain't working in Chrome (latest version)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually surprised Firefox renders that. You should really be using `position: absolute` in that case. Otherwise, the submenu is going to affect the dimensions of its parent.

Best practice AFAIK:

```
li {
 position:relative;
}

li ul {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 display:none;
}

li:hover ul {
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: the problem that will occur is that the sub-menu will have an absolute position. When I navigate to the second main-menu entry it's corresponding sub-menu will be displayed at the same position as for the first main-menu entry and it should be shown next to it. I added another screenshot for the second main-menue entry and it's sub-menu.

Comment: you are actually right but now I have a slight overlap from the sub-menu but only for the very first main-menu entry. I edited the snipplet.

Comment: That is because you need to add `position: relative` to all the `li`s, see my working example: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/fbh9fuma/ - I used the selector `ul.nav li { position: relative; }`